# what does & mean? C

Tags: c

i have this code :

```
#include<stdio.h>

   int main(void)
   {
    if (-8 & 7)
   {
       printf("Math is good -8 and 7 are both not zero\n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Everything we know is a lie!\n");
   }
    system("PAUSE");
    return (0);
   }
```

I'm new to C and my trying to figure out what this & operator does, can someone explain this to me?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

Comment: This is a simple typo or concept error; we should remove the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to your question, the program prints

```
Everything we know is a lie!
```

The bitwise operation of `&` is this

```
dec binary
-8  111111111111111111111000
 7  000000000000000000000111 
    ------------------------
 &  000000000000000000000000
```

However, the first statement

```
Math is good -8 and 7 are both not zero
```

would print if you used the logical operator `&&` because both `-8` and `7` are `true`.

Answer (score 1):

"&" is bitwise AND, which takes the corresponding bits of the 2 numbers, and ANDs them together. "&&" is the boolean AND operator that returns true/false depending on the value of the 2 conditions being compared.

Comment: There is another very important difference with `&&`.

Answer (score 1):

A single & is a bitwise and operator.. You can know more about it here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bitwise_operators.htm